# Problem with alignment and spacing with TextField with variant oulined in a FormControl. React and MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having some kind of problem with alignment and spacing in a React Form I'm building.

[Sceenshot of the Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6koxp.png)

As you can see, it seems like the textfield is properly aligned but it's ignoring the outline.

I would rather like the outline to be considered for spacing instead of the text field itself.

What am I missing?

Here is the code I'm using.

**My DescriptionControl component**

```
import { TextField, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';

export const DescriptionControl = ({ className, ...textFieldAttrs }) => (

  <FormControl fullWidth className>
    <TextField
      label="Description"
      type="description"
      name="description"
      variant="outlined"
      multiline
      {...textFieldAttrs}
    />
  </FormControl>
);
```

**The Form itself**

```
 <form onSubmit={articleSaveHandle}>

  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid container direction="row">
      <Grid container item xs={4}>
        <TitleControl
          className={classes.formControl}
          value={title}
          onChange={formInputChanged}
          helperText={(terrors.title || []).join(',')}
          required
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={4}>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="article-category-label">Catégorie</InputLabel>
          <SelectArticleCategory
            value={category}
            changed={formInputChanged}
            categoryList={useArticleCategories}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid container direction="row">
      <Grid container item xs={8}>
        <DescriptionControl
          className={classes.formControl}
          value={description}
          onChange={formInputChanged}
          helperText={(terrors.description || []).join(',')}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <br/>
    <Grid container direction="row">
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={articleSaveHandle}
        >
          {id && 'Modifier'}
          {!id && 'Ajouter'}
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be wrapping the `TextField` in a `FormControl`. The [outermost element rendered](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.0/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L156) by `TextField` is already `FormControl`. Instead, pass the `fullWidth` and `className` as properties directly on `TextField`.

Comment: Also, you need `className={className}` otherwise you are specifying it as a boolean property (which works fine for `fullWidth`).

Comment: Your problem is with the TextField or the Select component ?